# Delphi - Get line index and data index from given data

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tstringlist

So I have list of data that may contain different charters:

```
1dAAbt54
agFlE9dA
1295RTdd
```

First line data contains: `1d`, `AA`, `bt`, `54`. All I need is function that gives me the data of given index. Example: data of index 6 is `Fl` (Line - 2, Index in line is 2). Every line lenght is 8 and data length is 2;

How can I make such function in Delphi?

The result function should be something like this:

```
procedure (DataList: TStringList; DataIndex: Integer; var LineIndex: Integer; var PosInLine: Integer);
begin
//do the algorithm    
end;
```

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: You need to specify the format of the input data.

Comment: @Andreas If I understand correctly then it should be integer

Comment: But a `TStringList` doesn't contain integers, but strings... Your table, is it a `array[0..3, 0..2] of integer`, or a `TStringList`? In the latter case, what is the format of each row? Are the numbers separated by space? In your example above, the three first rows use double-space as separator, while the fourth use single space...

Comment: @Andreas it means that I didn't understand you, sorry,I don't know english so good. I don't know how to explain. Each line has charters inside it. For example `aabbcc1d` or `11..Dt..` (in this example there are 4 data values) (`11`, `..`, `Dt`, `..`) but still they are same length.

Comment: The values appear to be string representations of integers, stored in a TStringList (according to the tag). They appear to be arranged in a grid, or two dimensional array.

Comment: So, why not just traverse and search the string list?

Comment: Are you interested in efficiency? or just want a quick and simple solution?

Comment: With your edit, the question became completely different. Also, surely `bt` isn't an integer?

Comment: If I understood anything, your result function would look like a function instead of a procedure which would return the data at the given index.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: No, it should return the row and col of the first occurrence of the given data. UPDATE: Ooops, the Q has been changed again...

Comment: I had to give a -1 simply because the scope of the question has changed from its original format. When someone answers a question, then the question changes to something else, that answer no longer matches the question, therefore it makes the person who answered look bad. Please be sure to be thorough with your question before posting it.

Answer (score 7):

**Answer to the first version of your question**

The following is an answer to the *first version* of your question (before you edited it):

```
function GetIndexOfInteger(DataList: TStringList; DataIndex: Integer;
  out LineIndex: Integer; out PosInLine: Integer): boolean;
var
  x, y: Integer;
  InNum: boolean;
  NumStart: integer;
  ValIndex: integer;
begin
  result := false;
  for y := 0 to DataList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    InNum := false;
    ValIndex := 0;
    for x := 1 to Length(DataList[y]) do
    begin
      if (DataList[y][x] <> chr(32)) and not InNum then
      begin
        NumStart := x;
        InNum := true;
        inc(ValIndex);
      end;
      if InNum and ((DataList[y][x] = chr(32)) or
        (x = Length(DataList[y]))) then
      begin
        if StrToInt(Copy(DataList[y], NumStart, x - NumStart +
          IfThen(x = Length(DataList[y]), 1))) = DataIndex then
        begin
          LineIndex := y + 1;
          PosInLine := ValIndex;
          result := true;  // Roberts is on D7.
          Exit;            //
        end;
        InNum := false;
        Continue;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Try it:

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SR: TStringList;
  line, col: integer;
begin
  SR := TStringList.Create;
  SR.Add('1  2  3');
  SR.Add('4  5    6');
  SR.Add('7 8  9');
  SR.Add('10   11   12  13');

  if GetIndexOfInteger(SR, 13, line, col) then
    ShowMessage(Format('%d, %d', [line,col]));
end;
```

**Answer to the second version of your question**

(And this is so easy you could've done it yourself! :)

```
function GetIndexOfItemInListOfPairs(DataList: TStringList; Data: String; out LineIndex: Integer; out PosInLine: Integer): boolean;
var
  x, y: Integer;
begin
  result := false;
  for y := 0 to DataList.Count - 1 do
    for x := 0 to Length(DataList[y]) div 2 - 1 do
      if Copy(DataList[y], 2*x + 1, 2) = Data then
      begin
        LineIndex := y + 1;
        PosInLine := x + 1;
        Exit(true);
      end;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SR: TStringList;
  line,col:integer;
begin
  SR := TStringList.Create;
  SR.Add('1dAAbt54');
  SR.Add('agFlE9dA');
  SR.Add('1295RTdd');

  if GetIndexOfItemInListOfPairs(SR, 'RT', line, col) then
    ShowMessage(Format('%d, %d', [line,col]));

end;
```

**Answer to the third version of your question**

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RowIndex, ColIndex: Word;
begin

  DivMod(6 {index} - 1, 4 {items per row}, RowIndex, ColIndex);
  inc(RowIndex);
  inc(ColIndex);

  ShowMessageFmt('%d, %d', [RowIndex, ColIndex]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

```
procedure Search( DataList: TStringList; DataIndex: Integer; var LineIndex: Integer; var PosInLine: Integer);
var
  j, LineLen: integer;
  Line: string;
begin
LineIndex := 0;
PosInLine := 0;
for j := 0 to DataList.Count - 1 do
  begin
  Line := DataList[j];
  Inc( LineIndex);
  LineLen := Length( Line) div 2;
  if DataIndex >= LineLen then
    begin
    Dec( DataIndex, LineLen);
    continue
    end;
  PosInLine := LineLen;
  break
  end;    
if PosInLine = 0 then // No find
  LineIndex := 0
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops. The question has been changed completely. Here is the procedure for the question v 1.0 :)

```
procedure FindIndex(Data:TStringList; Index:integer;var LineIndex,PosInLine:Integer);
var i:integer;
    CurrentStr:String;
    StrToFind:String;
begin
    LineIndex:=0;
    PosInLine:=0;
    StrToFind:=intToStr(Index)+' ';
    for i:=0 to Data.Count-1 do
    begin
      CurrentStr:=' '+Data.Strings[i]+' ';
      IF POS(' '+StrToFind,CurrentStr)>0 then
      begin
        LineIndex:=i+1;
        //now we need to find PosInLine
        PosInLine:=1;
        repeat
          CurrentStr:=Trim(CurrentStr)+' ';
          IF Pos(StrToFind,CurrentStr)=1 then exit; //we found it

          CurrentStr:=copy(CurrentStr,POS(' ',CurrentStr),length(CurrentStr));
          inc(PosInLine);

        until (CurrentStr='');
        exit;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Tested with this code

```
var T:TStringList;
    Li,Pi:integer;
    i:integer;
begin
    T:=TStringList.Create();
    T.Add('1 2   3');
    T.Add('  4 5    6');
    T.Add('7 8 9');
    T.Add('10 11 12  ');
    for i:=0 to 13 do
    begin
      FindIndex(T,i,Li,Pi);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i)+':'+IntToStr(Li)+'-'+IntToStr(Pi))
    end;
end;
```